# Why I get 2 different outputs for 'whoami' command in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, php, chown

I got here from StackOverflow because I couldn't find a solution there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146827/permission-denied-for-file-upload-in-php) is the link to the question.

When I open terminal and type `whoami` I get `m1ck0` which is my user. But when I enter `whoami` command in PHP

```php
echo exec('whoami');
```

I get `http` and this is causing me the problem where I can't make image upload with PHP. It says

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../images/cart.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/http/portfolio/admin/backend/write/blogs.php
```

I think that this is because I don't have ownership of that folder. But output of `ls -l` is

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 m1ck0 m1ck0 4096 13. nov. at 21:18 portfolio
```

for the root directory of project and

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 m1ck0 m1ck0 4096 13. nov. at 21:18 images
```

for a directory where I want to upload the image to.

Thank you in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I also tried with an absolute path to the directory and still got the same error.

**UPDATE 2** 
I am using `OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64`

Comment: Do you really *enter* the command in PHP, or are you executing it from a script in a web page? It is normal for a web server to run as user `http`.

Comment: I am executing it from a PHP script right before I try to move a file to desired folder

Comment: Well, the HTTP server (Apache HTTP Server, Nginx) is not *you*. You could configure it to run under your user account, but that would be both insecure and unusual. You must develop your application taking into consideration that the web server runs under a dedicated service account.

Comment: Any tips or links that you can point me to?

Comment: If you are using Apache HTTP Server, you could start with Ivan Ristić's [*Apache security*](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/apache-security/online/index.html); it is an (old and) gentle introduction to the topic. Once you make sure that you understand that little book many things will become more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I really need things like this book :)

Comment: Read the "Preface to the Digital Reprint"; you may want to get his book about Mod_Security (which is really the only major change between the date the book was written and today). Note that the author is the person who actually wrote a large part of the security aspects of Apache, so he knows what he is speaking about.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to understand this as better as possible